# Does it make sense to use Tensorflow Dataset over a Keras DataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am training a model using `tf.keras` and I have many small `.npy` files with single observations in a folder on local disk. I have build a `DataGeneretor(keras.utils.Sequence)` class and it works correctly, although I have a warning:

`'tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended.'`

I have found out that I can simply create something like this:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    DataGenerator, args=[...], 
    output_types=(tf.float16, tf.uint8), 
    output_shapes=([None,256,256,3], [None,256,256,1]),
)
```

and then my Keras DataGenerator would work as a single file reader and a TF Dataset as interface to create batches. My question is: does it make any sense? Would it be safer? Would it read next batch during the training of previous batch, when using simple `model.fit`?

Comment: What do you mean by safer?

Comment: I meant it in the context of the warning: `tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks`.